# RxJs Partition if then else

Tags: angular, rxjs

If the url param contains no null ID, call getUserDetails, and getOrganization List.
If the url param doesn't contain, id, just call getOrganization.
But problem is combine latest is not called for scenario 2.

```
    let [updateUser$, createUser$] = this.route.params
          .map((params: Params) => params['id'])
          .partition(id => !!id);


   updateUser$ = updateUser$
      .do(() => {
        this.isEdit = true;
      })
      .flatMap(id => this.userService.getUserById(id))
      .map(user => {

        let languageId = user['languageId'];
        let organization = user['organization'];
        let organizationObj = [{ id: organization, text: organization }];
        return Object.assign(user, { languageId: [{ id: languageId, text: languageId }] }, { organization: organizationObj });
      });


    let getOrganization$ = this.userService.getOrganization();


    Observable.combineLatest(getOrganization$, updateUser$, (organizationList: any, user: any) => {
      return {
        organizationList: organizationList,
        user: user
      };
    })
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        // pre populate the form
        let user = data.user;
        if (user) {
          Object.keys(user).forEach(key => {
            const control = this.userForm.get(key);
            if (control) {
              control.setValue(user[key]);
              control.markAsDirty(true);
            }
          });
        }

        this.organizationList = data.organizationList.map(o => o.name);

      }, err => this.error(err));


     Observable.combineLatest(getOrganization$, createUser$, (organizationList: any) => {
      return {
        organizationList: organizationList,
      };
    })
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.organizationList = data.organizationList.map(o => o.name);
      }, err => this.error(err));
```

how should i model this problem with rxjs

Comment: i do not see why the second combineLatest does not work if the first one dow, but i can tell that  this.userService.getOrganization will be called twice since each combine latest uses it. observables are cold - two subscribtion. Also not sure ow often this params should get new ids, getOrganization$  in each combine - will emit only one value if this is http and complete, so it means each combine will emit max one value.

Comment: ya, 2nd combine latest is also called. 
params (id) is called on ngOnInit, i'm using same component for create user and update user, Is there any simpler way to acheive the same solution.
So only one combine latest will called, so only one getOrganziation$ per page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that will do the work. Replace dummy observables with http and route ones. this is just a simulator.

```
let routes$ = Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
  observer.next({id:1});
  setTimeout(()=>  observer.next({xx:1}), 1000);
  setTimeout(()=>  observer.next({id:2}), 2000);
  setTimeout(()=>  observer.next({xx:2}), 3000);
  setTimeout(()=>  observer.next({id:3}), 4000);
});

let [updateUser$, createUser$] =
   routes$
  .map(params=> params['id'])
  .partition(id => !!id);


 updateUser$
  .switchMap(id=>Rx.Observable.of(`${id}_user`))
  .switchMap(user=>Rx.Observable.of('organizationList'),
        (user, organizationList) => ({user, organizationList})
 ).subscribe(x=>console.log(x));

 createUser$
   .switchMap(id=>Rx.Observable.of('organizationList'))
   .map(organizationList=> ({organizationList}))
   .subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
```